# How can I change image source in javascript using "this"?

Tags: javascript, this, src

I have a div element with id = "image" having no background-image initially.
I have an another image, on which when I hover, somefunction(this) is called.
Now, I want this function to change that div's background image to the hovered image.
I am doing something like this...

## HTML:

```
<div id = "image"> a division </div>
<img class = "abc" onmouseover = somefunction(this) src ="someimage.jpg>
```

## CSS:

```
#image{ background-image : url(''); }
```

## JS:

```
function somefunction(element)
{
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.background.src = element.src;
}
```

But It's not working anyway, and I want to do this using "this" only.

Comment: try `x.style.backgroundImage = element.src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```js
function somefunction(element)
 {
  var x = document.getElementById('image');
  x.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+element.src+"')"
 }
```

```html
 <div id = "image"> a division </div>
 <img class = "abc" onmouseover="somefunction(this);" src="your path to file.PNG"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ab Mishra, this code is perfectly working as also mentioned by SudhirBastakoti

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few `""` in your HTML inline styles/attributes;

Plus, use `backgroundImage` + variable/string concatenation in your javaScript function. And also add a default `background-image` css style on your `#image` div.

Also use `camelCase` when naming functions/variables in javaScript. So `somefunction` should be `someFunction`.

```js
function someFunction(element)
{
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    console.log()
    x.style.backgroundImage ='url('+element.src+')';
}
```

```css
#image {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background-image:none;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "image"> a division </div>
<img class = "abc" onmouseover="someFunction(this)" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function somefunction(element){
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://s9.tinypic.com/mb4bux_th.jpg')"
    console.log("div's background changed")
}
```

```html
<div id = "image"> a division </div>
 <img class = "abc" onmouseover = somefunction(this) src="http://s9.tinypic.com/2lv1yrt_th.jpg"/>
```